# Можно ли полноценно управлять VPS хостингом череp ssh?

Tags: ssh, vps, хостинг

Проблема в том, что на хостинге нет никакой панели управления.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Конечно.

> SSH (англ. Secure SHell — «безопасная оболочка») — сетевой протокол сеансового уровня, позволяющий производить удалённое управление операционной системой и туннелирование TCP-соединений (например, для передачи файлов). Сходен по функциональности с протоколами Telnet и rlogin, но, в отличие от них, шифрует весь трафик, включая и передаваемые пароли.

Это безопасно и удобно! На сайте вашего хостинга должны быть инструкции по подключению через SSH. Подробности всегда можно найти в гугле.

На сайте хостинга конечно не будет никакой панели, так как подключение осуществляется через SSH-клиенты: PuTTy, OpenSSH

Comment: Не знаю, используются ли на VPS программы для XWindows, но туннель Х11 через SSH -- дело обычное.

Answer (score 4):

Зависит от того, что считать полноценным.

Обычное администрирование *nix-системы — да, конечно, так обычно и делают. SSH позволяет выполнять команды (в частности, запускать редакторы для правки файлов), панели делают то же самое (из фиксированного набора команд и изменений файлов).

Но если разломаете систему так, что она перестанет грузиться — например, неудачным обновлением дистрибутива — sshd не запустится и нужны будут более другие меры. У традиционного железа это, как правило, IPMI; у XEN'овых и KVM'ных виртуалок — VNC или telnet-доступ к виртуальному терминалу или COM-порту; у всяких OpenVZ все сложнее вплоть до невозможности самостоятельно починить неисправность (тогда только техподдержка хостера, и не факт, что она будет сговорчива).